# create a nested dictionary from dataframe, where first column is the key for parent dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested dictionary from a pandas dataframe. The first column-values are supposed to be the key for the upper dictionary, which will contaion the other columns as dictionary, where the column header is the key. I would like to avoid loops.

the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'C': [1.0, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0, 1.0]})
```

what I would like to have:

```
dict_expt = {'11': {'B': [1, 2, 3],
                  'C': [1.0, 0.7, 0.3]},
           '12': {'B': [4, 5],
                  'C': [1.0]}}
```

what I have tried:

```
df.groupby(['A']).agg({'B':lambda x: list(x.unique()),
                      'C':lambda x: list(x.unique())}).to_dict()
```

which unfortunately returns:

```
{'B': 
     {11: [1, 2, 3], 
      12: [4, 5]}, 
'C': {11: [1.0, 0.7, 0.3], 
      12: [1.0]}}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just add `"index"` to `to_dict()`:

```
df.groupby(['A']).agg({'B':lambda x: list(x.unique()),
                      'C':lambda x: list(x.unique())}).to_dict("index")
```

Output:

```
{11: {'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [1.0, 0.7, 0.3]}, 12: {'B': [4, 5], 'C': [1.0]}}
```

Comment: Ahahahaha. That was so easy. Massive thanks. I tried so much, that in the end I just failed to progress. Cheers